# Use Selenium to attach to a manually opened Browser

Tags: c#, wpf, selenium, browser, driver

I know, that such a question is already asked here before, but it is 4 years old and not quite helpful.
So, what i want to do is simple, i want my selenium (running in WPF and .Net 5.0 in c#) so connect to an open browser to control it. The browser is opened manually with the debuggingport 9222 and i can successfull connect to this browser from another browser instance.

i am able to open a NEW Chrome browser with selenium and control it, but i need to also have the ability to connect to an open instance.

and help would be awesome.

PS: i know that selenium is for testing, and normally not used to not be in a controlled test-environment. =)

thank you so much for you help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Type : **chrome://version/** in browser you will get executable path of chrome.exe

copy this and close all chrome instance.

**close all chrome instance and **

**start chrome as:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=5555
```

verify chrome is started with port open by going to localhost:5555

**Now add remote debugging port as:**

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.debuggerAddress= "127.0.0.1:5555";

var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

use chrromeoptions to connect to that port from selenium

Comment: this is exactly the way i currently do it. but this is NOT the way i asked for here.
i want to NOT need to open a browser from core like you did. 
i want to connect to a browser that is already open

Comment: PDHide maybe you know of a way to set up chrome in such a way that when it is manually opened (not through ChromeDriver) but manual operation, to have a default remote debugging port set up?

Comment: @LaurianAvrigeanu in windows you can add arguments by opening properties ,

Comment: @PDHide you misunderstand, I want it to open with that port open by default whenever an user opens chrome via Windows (by clicking or double clicking), so that I can attach a chromedriver to it, opening it manually from code behind can't achieve what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I tried going to chrome://inspect and port forward it as well but that didn't do anything as chromedriver can't attach to it.